# How to limit scrapy to a particular section of a website, e.g. http://www.domain.com/section/

Tags: scrapy

I have a scrapy project which crawls all the internal links of a given website. This is working fine, however we have found a few situations where we want to limit the crawling to a particular section of a website.

For example, if you could imagine a bank has a special section for investor information, e.g. http://www.bank.com/investors/

So in the example above, everything in http://www.bank.com/investors/ only would be crawled. For example, http://www.bank.com/investors/something/, http://www.bank.com/investors/hello.html, http://www.bank.com/investors/something/something/index.php

I know I could write some hacky code on parse_url which scans the URL and does a pass if it doesn't meet my requirements (i.e. it's not /investors/), but that seems horrible.

Is there a nice way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

You need to add an allow() for the pattern you want to allow.

For example:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(self.this_folder_only)), callback="parse_url", follow=True)
```

Everything else will be denied.